# Change 1 word of an css attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code

```
    <span style="background-image:url('/product_images/attribute_value_images/78.thumbnail.jpg')" class="thumbnail">&nbsp;</span>
```

I need to change the word thumbnail for preview, it is possible with jquery?

so far I have this:

```
    $("li.swatch span.thumbnail").each(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image").replace(/thumbnail/ig, "preview")
    ;
    });
```

it seems to be working (if I alert() I get the right value) but is not changing in the page.. any ideas where I could look up? thx in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `.css(propertyName)` only **gets** the css rule value of *propertyName*.

So in your code, your are getting the css, replacing its content, but not updating back the css rule afterwards.

Use the other overload `.css(propertyName, value)` after obtaining/modifying the css rule to update the rule:

```
$("li.swatch span.thumbnail").each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        // get the css rule and changing it
        css = $this.css("background-image").replace(/thumbnail/ig, "preview");

    // update the css rule
    $this.css('background-image', css );

});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) on .css().